# What's the simplest & most efficient way of telling if your code is executing on the client or the server?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET (C#) class that is used both on the client and server.

Depending on whether the code is being executed on the client or the server, it needs to behave differently.

What is the simplest & most efficient way of telling if the code is executing on the client or the server?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify more about your situation, in particular what kind of code/framework you're dealing with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

unless you are running Silverlight 2 or Silverlight 3 There is no way for Asp.Net to run C# code in the client (the users' browser)

Comment: There is: a .NET WinForms user control ;)

Answer (score 2):

It's executing on the server. Unless you are using Silverlight, C# is probably not run on the client.

Comment: Do you mean "ASP.NET is probably not run on the client"?

Comment: No, I used the word probably since there are other ways except Silverlight: a WinForms user control, an XBAP application, among others

Answer (score 2):

Unless we're talking Silverlight here, there's not much choice: C# code is always executed on the server, JavaScript is executed on the client.

Answer (score 2):

By your tags I see your talking about a web application not a client-server winforms app.

If it is in javascript, html and css, or silverlight it's happening in the browser. If it is happening in C#, it's happening on the server.